# node.js Cannot find module './lib/compat'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running a JavaScript code on Ubuntu server using node.js 
I got this error.

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './lib/compat'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/node_modules/express/node_modules/depd/index.js:11:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

How to debug this error?

Edit: using these dependencies.

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
```

Comment: What other dependencies do you have? Something you are using may be old enough it is not directly compatible with Node.

Comment: That error is about module.require. Seems like you are requiring/including a file that does not exist (file path wrong maybe). Look at your code for './lib/compat'.

Comment: I edited the code and checked for your proposition. It's not about includinga file that doesn't exist...

Comment: Show us your node application file!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not directly in your code, but in the dependency of one of the modules you're using. You see it at this line of the error message:

```
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/node_modules/express/node_modules/depd/index.js:11:24)
```

`express` module has a dependency called `depd`, which is the module in trouble.

How did you install your modules?

There has **probably been some problem when you have installed express**.

The folder `lib/compat` is [directly part of depd](https://github.com/dougwilson/nodejs-depd), so there's no reason it should be missing.

You may want to do the following:

```
npm uninstall express
npm install express --save
```

This would reinstall express, hopefully solving the issue.

Answer (score 10):

The problem can persist even after running:

```
npm uninstall express
npm install express --save
```

If this happens delete the node-modules folder and then run:

```
npm install express
```

and

```
npm install
```

to reinstall all the packages listed in packages.json

Comment: this worked for me, thank you! clearing everything and installing express first before anything else.

Comment: Exactly for my case that I need to delete `node-modules` folder and npm install express afterwards. It does not help just by `npm uninstall` with a `npm install`.